# Why does href="/" direct to the system files?

Tags: html, apache, anchor

When I request the page on the hosting device it directs me to the local system files. If I request the page from a different device it returns the correct index.html page. This is the anchor element being used for the request.

```
<a id="indexLink" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
```

Why is the host machine directed to the system files?

Comment: what web server?

Comment: @DanielA.White Apache. For right now, everything is hosted locally.

Comment: When you open the web page are you opening the file via a localhost URL, or by double-clicking the file? If you see the `file://` protocol in the url of the page that would – probably – explain it (since it’s being treated as a file and not running through the server).

Comment: @DavidThomas Good point. I checked and it was the file being opened instead of the localhost file. Which explains why the issue was isolated to the local machine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I’m glad to have helped, if you’d care to put together an answer for your question it would be much appreciated that way this question is of use to others in future. (I don’t know if it’s a duplicate or not, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the file is opened from the system (double-clicking on the file) then, `href="/"` directs the user to the system file requested. This is because the link looks something like this `file://example/openedPage.html`. Thus, when href directs the user to `"/"` it actually directs the user to the file path of `file:///` on the system.

To check if the link works, the localhost (or external host) file must be requested instead. This link will look something like `localNetworkAddress/pageName.html`.